# aws-iot-device-sdk is undefined when bundled with rollup

Tags: javascript, rollup, aws-iot, rollupjs

I am using aws-iot-device-sdk library for websocket connections, and bundling it all with rollup.
I have the following config:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import async from 'rollup-plugin-async';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import { minify } from 'uglify-es';

const pkg = require('./package.json');

export default {
    name: 'InPlayer',
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.browser,
            format: 'umd',
        },
        {
            file: 'examples/js/inplayer.js',
            format: 'umd',
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        builtins(),
        async(),
        replace({
            ENVIRONMENT: JSON.stringify('production'),
        }),
        babel({
            exclude: ['node_modules/**'],
        }),
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            jsnext: true,
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            namedExports: {
                'node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/index.js': ['aws-iot-device-sdk'],
            }
        }),
        uglify({}, minify),
        globals(),
        json(),
    ],
    external: ['es6-promise/auto', 'aws-iot-device-sdk'],
    exports: 'named',
    context: 'self',
    acorn: {
        ecmaVersion: 8,
    },
};
```

However when i try:

```
import awsIot from 'aws-iot-device-sdk';
console.log(awsIot);
```

awsIot is always undefined, no matter what. I also used aws-iot-device-sdk inside a React Applicaiton and imported it just like this - worked like a charm.
However I am not sure what am I doing wrong here with Rollup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about the specific sdk in particular, but from what I have gathered aws-sdk's, in general, are implicitly non-compatible with rollup as of now.

Please look into this discussion :

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1769